# How to concurrently run asynchronous launchers/concurrently run asyncio functions in a big manager

Tags: python, performance, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to make my code run faster for finding roblox account names. I tried using larger and larger event loops (they basically took the previous event manager and used that to make a larger event manager), but that resulted in the same, if not worse performance when compared to using just a single small event loop.

This code was supplied in another question of mine (with modifications from me here). It works great, but it still can take a good few minutes to handle larger quantities of accounts. Usually I wouldn't care, but I am trying to get to 100,000 accounts, so I need performance. Is this just how fast it can go? Or can we drive this even further? Is the answer just more CPU/memory? Better internet? Do I need network programming at all, or is there a faster, no-request way?

Code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def find_account(url, session, id):
    try:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                r = await response.read()
                from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
                h2 = []
                for i in soup.find_all('h2'):
                    h2.append(i)
                print('Done')
                return str(list(list(h2)[0])[0]) + '  ' + str(url)
            else:
                return 'This account does not exist ID: {}'.format(id)
    except aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError:
        print('Done')
        return find_account(url, session, id)


async def main(min_id, max_id):
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for id in range(min_id, max_id):
            url = f'https://web.roblox.com/users/{str(id)}/profile'
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(find_account(url=url, session=session, id=id)))

        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


from time import time
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
starting = int(input("Type Your Starting Id Number>> "))
ending = int(input("Type Your Ending Id Number>> "))
timer = time()
users = loop.run_until_complete(main(starting, ending))
users = [i for i in users if i != '1']
print(users)
print(time()-timer)
```

Comment: I'm curious, how much time is used to parse vs. time to process http requests. I'm guessing most of the time is spent constructing  beautifulsoup objects. Also why do you have an import in the middle of your code? I think there is still a lot of work to do on your side before anyone can really help you.

Comment: hmmmm... good point. I'm going to try and straighten out the code, and find a more efficient parser.

Comment: First measure it, I'm not sure that's the issue, just a guess.

Comment: Processing time for request: 0.30557966232299805
Processing time for parser: 0.014953136444091797

Comment: So, if I get it right, its close to 25 minutes for parsing 100k pages? What's the total user time of this script for 100k entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run `BeautifulSoup` in multiple processes to speed it up. For example, you can extract the part of `find_account` that does the parsing and pass that to a process pool executor:

```
import concurrent.futures
_pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()

def parse(html):
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    h2 = []
    for i in soup.find_all('h2'):
        h2.append(i)
    return str(list(list(h2)[0])[0])

async def find_account(url, session, id):
    while True:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                r = await response.read()
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                extracted = await loop.run_in_executor(_pool, parse, r)
                print('Done')
                return extracted + '  ' + str(url)
            else:
                return 'This account does not exist ID: {}'.format(id)
    except aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError:
        print('Done')
        # keep looping
```

On an unrelated note, your recursive call to `find_account()` was incorrect because it was missing an `await`. The above code fixes that and switches to a loop instead, which makes it a bit more explicit that the code is in fact looping.

Comment: I wasn't able to find much better performance... thanks for helping though!

Comment: @Arandomcoder You can also try passing a custom [`TCPConnector`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#limiting-connection-pool-size) when creating the session, one with a larger connection limit. (The default is 100.) If none of that helps, perhaps the host is limiting you or is itself limited in how much it can deliver.